# How to move functions outside a loop

Tags: javascript

JSHint is screaming that functions should be declared outside the loop, I'm just confused on how to do this? The specific part: self.onchange = function () {...}

Here's the loop:

```
for ( var j = 0; j < checkz.length; j++ ) {
    var self = checkz[j];
    self.onchange = function () {
        for ( var z = 0; z < psswrd.length; z++ ) {
            psswrd[z].type = self.checked ? 'text' : 'password';
        }
    };
}
```

When I move it outside and assign it, the function breaks as 'self' becomes undefined. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @NetaMeta Pass JSHint validation as I am using Grunt.js

Comment: Apart from declaring the function outside, this code is buggy.

Comment: Some more detail and suggestions can be found in [this article on JSLintErrors.com](http://jslinterrors.com/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case, you just need one function:

```
for ( var j = 0; j < checkz.length; j++ ) {
    var self = checkz[j];
    self.onchange = changeFunction;
    // Or replace the above two lines with:
    // checkz[j].onchange = changeFunction;
    // ...if you don't need `self` for anything else.
}

function changeFunction() {
    for ( var z = 0; z < psswrd.length; z++ ) {
        psswrd[z].type = this.checked ? 'text' : 'password';
        //               ^^^^--- note this changed from `self` to `this`
    }
}
```

You needed that `self` => `this` change anyway, because as it was originally, all of the functions would have referred to the **same** value of `self`. When you create a function, it has an enduring reference to the variables in context where it's created, not a copy of their values when it's created. (More: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)) In this case, we can use `this` because within an event handler hooked up that way (and most ways), `this` will be the element the event handler was hooked up to.

---

Now in the general case, where sometimes you need to refer to something that's changing in the loop and you don't happen to have a replacement handy for it, you'd typically use a builder function that returns the function to use, like this:

```
for ( var j = 0; j < checkz.length; j++ ) {
    var self = checkz[j];
    self.onchange = buildChangeFunction(j);
}

function buildChangeFunction(jarg) {
    return function() {
        // Use jarg in here...
    };
}
```

That way, the function we assign to `onchange` closes over the argument to `buildChangeFunction`, not `j`, and that argumennt doesn't change.

But again, you don't need that here, the first solution above is all you need.

Comment: That change is definitely more than important, as it fixes the bug in the original version.