# Moving function outside a loop

Tags: jquery, function, loops

I have read the solution on the following page but still don't understand how to apply it to my loop and function. How do I move the following function outside the loop?

[How to move functions outside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657113/how-to-move-functions-outside-a-loop)

```
var i;
    var chap = '.nav__chapter-';
        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        var precedingZero = (i<10) ? '0' : '';
            (function(i) {
                $( chap + precedingZero + i ).addClass('toggleAria');
            })(i);
        }
```

I have a few like this so once I understand it I can apply to all. Sorry for being so dense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need your IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) in the loop at all.  You can change to just this:

```
var chap = '.nav__chapter-', precedingZero;
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    precedingZero = (i < 10) ? '0' : '';
    $(chap + precedingZero + i).addClass('toggleAria');
}
```

An IIFE might be used inside a loop if you have async operations and you need to "save" a loop value for later use in an async callback.  But, that is not happening at all here so the IIFE is simply not needed.